# gitlab installation duplicated schema problem occurs on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitlab-ee

while installing gitlab on ubuntu machine using
`apt install gitlab-ce`
i receive this message

```
PG::DuplicateSchema: ERROR:  schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20211202041233_init_schema.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:121:in `public_send'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:121:in `block in write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:127:in `block in read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:198:in `retry_with_backoff'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:116:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:120:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:72:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:369:in `block in transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:368:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/lock_retry_mixin.rb:36:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/pg_backend_pid.rb:15:in `block in with_advisory_lock_connection'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/pg_backend_pid.rb:12:in `with_advisory_lock_connection'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:117:in `configure_database'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:95:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

i have checked the migration file, but t doesnt contain any duplication of schema creation. i tried to log into postgresql too, but no database , table or schema is associated with gitlab. maybe it uses some other instance of database. problem occurs both using gitlab-ce or gitlab-ee package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to log into PostgreSQL too, but no database, table or schema is associated with gitlab.

Maybe you are not logged in to the right database: The error message you are seeing, `PG::DuplicateSchema: ERROR:  schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists`, suggests that GitLab is trying to create a schema in PostgreSQL that already exists.

The `\dn` command in PostgreSQL should list all schemas. If you can't find the schema, it may be that GitLab is connecting to a different PostgreSQL server or database.

So check the database GitLab is using: GitLab stores its database configuration in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. Look for `gitlab_rails['db_']` configuration values, especially `gitlab_rails['db_database']` (which should be `gitlabhq_production` by default), `gitlab_rails['db_host']`, and `gitlab_rails['db_port']`. These should tell you which PostgreSQL server and database GitLab is using.
If not, check if you see a `config/database.yml`. Or en environment variable referencing a PostGreSQL database.